# Output of running commands in Terminal

Tags: command-line, find

I use this line to delete files

```
find . -type f -iname \*.vi -delete
```

and this line to move files

```
find . -name "*.doc" -exec mv {} /path
```

How can I see the process as it happen, I mean I don't see any output, and it only shows when the process is done.

Comment: you have missed a `;` at the end in the second example..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not enable verbosity natively in `find`.

You need to use `rm -v` with `find`'s `-exec` action, instead of `find`'s native action `-delete`:

```
find . -type f -iname \*.vi -exec rm -v {} +
```

In the second case, use `mv -v`:

```
find . -name "*.doc" -exec mv -v {} /path \;
```

Or better:

```
find . -name "*.doc" -exec mv -vt /path {} +
```

In both cases, `-v` tells `rm`/`mv` to become verbose to say whats being done.

Comment: Thank you so much , btw is there a way to enter more than one file extension to these commands ?

Comment: @MohammadAlzorgan Of course..see http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/15308/68757

Comment: You can enable verbosity natively with `-print`

Answer (score 1):

Another way around is to tell `find` to `print` the filename before executing another action:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 2 -iname 'foo.txt'
./foo.txt
$ find . -maxdepth 2 -iname 'foo.txt' -print -delete
./foo.txt
$ ll ./foo.txt
ls: cannot access ./foo.txt: No such file or directory
```